# Chart series are not shown until clicking on scrollbar

Tags: c#, .net, charts

Here is my init method for the chart in my C# program.

```
private void initGraph()
{  
    chartTrend.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.LineColor = Color.Red;
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.LineWidth = 2;
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot;            
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;

    // let us select a portion of chart so then zoom that portion
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Interval =1 ;
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;

    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.AutoScroll = false;
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = true;
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;

    // disable zoom-reset button (only scrollbar's arrows are available)
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;           
    chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 528;
}
```

The problem is that, when I add data to the chart, It will not be shown until I click on the scroll. I even tried to move the scroll by software but it didn't work. what can I do?

By the way, it is all for the last line of `initGraph()` method. when I comment it out, data will be shown, but in the way that I'm not interested.

Comment: You can try to add a [`chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.recalculateaxesscale(v=vs.110).aspx) at the end of the init.. Note that without data nothing can be shown!

Comment: @TaW thanks, but it doesn't work. I knew it and even add your code after adding data but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the position of scroll. I understood that when I added data to the chart, It was depicting chart from a time which was far away from the start of my time range and after clicking on the scroll, it took it to the proper time. So I decided to move the scroll after adding my first points and finally, the problem solved by this line:

```
chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = chartTrend.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum;
```